# Traverse through inner join result using cursor

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I am very new to the oracle database stored procedure, so please forgive me if i am asking very simple or basic question.

*I want to traverse through inner join result set which was produced in procedure using cursor.*

I have created one procedure which have a simple SQL select query joing tow table and selection fields from both the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE demoprocedure(crsr out SYS_REFCURSOR)  
AS 
      BEGIN
      OPEN crsr FOR
        SELECT 
            TABLE1.field1, TABLE2.field2, TABLE1.fields11, TABLE2.field22
        FROM 
            TABLE1 INNER JOIN   
            TABLE2   
        ON 
            TABLE1.field12 = TABLE2.field12
END demoprocedure;
```

I want to traverse this result set using cursor, here is what i have tried

```
DECLARE
  crsr SYS_REFCURSOR;
  temp SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  demoprocedure(crsr);
  LOOP
    FETCH crsr INTO temp;
        EXIT WHEN crsr%NOTFOUND;
        Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Fields1 is : ' || temp.field1);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE crsr;
END;
```

But this is not working, well i have tried creating custom object but is also gives error.

**Expected result:**

```
Fields1 is : 1
Fields1 is : 2
Fields1 is : 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the declaration of the temp variable. You can fetch the content of the `SYS_REFCURSOR` in a local variable and then display it as following:

**Procedure**:

> ```
> SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DEMOPROCEDURE (
>   2      CRSR OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
>   3  ) AS
>   4  BEGIN
>   5      OPEN CRSR FOR SELECT
>   6                        'ABC' AS COL1,
>   7                        'BCD' AS COL2,
>   8                        'CDE' AS COL3,
>   9                        'DEF' AS COL4
>  10                    FROM
>  11                        DUAL;
>  12
>  13  END DEMOPROCEDURE;
>  14  /
>
> Procedure created.
> ```

**Testing it (Loop through it)**

> ```
> SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON;
> SQL> DECLARE
>   2      CRSR     SYS_REFCURSOR;
>   3      V_COL1   VARCHAR2(100);
>   4      V_COL2   VARCHAR2(100);
>   5      V_COL3   VARCHAR2(100);
>   6      V_COL4   VARCHAR2(100);
>   7  BEGIN
>   8      DEMOPROCEDURE(CRSR);
>   9      LOOP
>  10          FETCH CRSR INTO
>  11              V_COL1,
>  12              V_COL2,
>  13              V_COL3,
>  14              V_COL4;
>  15          EXIT WHEN CRSR%NOTFOUND;
>  16          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fields1 is : ' || V_COL1);
>  17          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fields2 is : ' || V_COL2);
>  18          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fields3 is : ' || V_COL3);
>  19          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fields4 is : ' || V_COL4);
>  20      END LOOP;
>  21
>  22      CLOSE CRSR;
>  23  END;
>  24  /
> Fields1 is : ABC
> Fields2 is : BCD
> Fields3 is : CDE
> Fields4 is : DEF
>
> PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: I have a issue with inner join, please review question again, i have selected fields from both the table @Tejash

Comment: What is the issue in Join? I cant see any

Comment: I need to define type resultset as you have defined temp as VARCHAR(10), as your query is returning varchar(10), but here in my case i am returning 4 fields from two different tables, so can you help me how i can do that?

Comment: Ok, Updated the answer. Check now!!